# how to mirror an hourglass with no more than four for loops?

Tags: java

I would like to find out how to mirror one half hourglass... with not more than 4 loops.  I do not want to use recursion or arrays, just simple for loops

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter odd number above 0 here: ");
    int h = sc.nextInt();
    char x = '#';

    if (h % 2 != 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++) {

            // loop for first part of hourglass
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            // create white space
            for (int j = h - i; j >= 1; j--) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            // create mirror
            for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--) {
                System.out.print(x);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println(" Not an odd number. Try again: ");
    }
```

Comment: Please improve the grammar. Sentences begin with a capital letter, same like in German.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do the same `for loop`, with a simple change in the iterator:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter odd number above 0 here: ");
    int h = sc.nextInt();
    char x = '#';

    if (h % 2 != 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 2*h; i++) {

            int a = Math.abs(h-i);
            // loop for first part of hourglass
            for (int j = a; j < h; j++) {
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            // create white space
            for (int j = 0; j <a; j++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            for (int j = a; j < h; j++) {
                System.out.print(x);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(" Not an odd number. Try again: ");
    }
```

Comment: sure Kepotx, but do you think thats the least amount of for loops you could use for that problem? 

my professor told me, its possible within four loops., so im trying :-)

Comment: @grinsekatz007 I edit it, only four loop, is it better know?

Comment: yes, thank you, i think i was looking for that... but i dont get it yet, how a manipulates the loops in that way.. thats interesting. thank you!

Comment: so, a controls the pattern mostly, right? from the middle (done with h -i) right?  
but why does it now work up and downwards? because a first decreases and then increases again, am i on track?

Comment: @grinsekatz007 notice that a is not h-i but abs(h-i), ie the distance between h and i

Answer (score 1):

Build first half in a String[] array, then print it normally then backwards. You could do this for the vertical symmetry as well.

Comment: true, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one for-loop and remove all the nested for loop actually, try below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter odd number above 0 here: ");
    int h = sc.nextInt();
    String x = "#";

    if (h % 2 != 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
            String hash = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", x);
            System.out.print(hash);
            String spaces = new String(new char[2*(h-i)]).replace("\0", " ");
            System.out.print(spaces);
            System.out.print(hash);

            System.out.println();
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println(" Not an odd number. Try again: ");
    }
}
```

Not sure is it what you are looking for, but they have same result eventually.
I have changed `x` from `char` to `String` as well for `replace` function. If you want to keep `x` as `char`, you can do `String.valueOf(x)` in the `replace()`.